# My chrome extension doesn't display short_name and default_icon

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm building my first chrome extension, which replaces the New Tab. I'm trying to change the icon and name of the tab with:

```
"short_name": "New Tab",
"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "img/icon32.png"
}
```

but all I see in the actual tab's header is "chrome://newtab" and no icon. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: To replace the new tab you need to specify your html file in [chrome_url_overrides](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/override). Since it's a standard page, you can specify the name in `<title>` tag, and favicon in `<link>` tag, you can find examples easily.

Comment: thanks! I thought for some reason that I can override this in the manifest..